# Finding beginning 0s but not the last one if it's the last character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string. I want the regex to replace all leading 0s, excluding the last one if it's the last character in the string.

The only case that is true (the last character being 0) is if the entire string is 0s.

Here is the regex I have:

```
/^0+/
```

I need it extended to fit the criteria I mentioned. Currently it would replace `"0000"` with `""`

Here are some *expected* sample input/outputs:

```
"0000"   --> "0"
"0"      --> "0"
"0010"   --> "10"
"1"      --> "1"
"100050" --> "100050"
"09A"    --> "9A"
```

Note: I realize I could just disclude the last character when replacing the string and it should work, but I'm interested in the regex for it. I also realize I could simply have an if-statement because my current regex only fails in one case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work (in that it matches your expected outputs from your sample inputs):

```
.replace(/^0+(?!$)/g,'')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/74wD9/1/).

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `0+` matches the character 0 literally, Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `(?!$)` Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
- `$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: Works exactly as expected and this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you. I see that all you added was `(?!$)`.

Comment: Yup, the good ol' negative lookahead :) (though do note that [Explosion Pills' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23974733/82548) is slightly less verbose/incomprehensible...)

Answer (score 5):

Using `parseInt(string, 10)` should do what you need (the second argument is important so that some interpreters do not treat the string as octal).

If you really wanted to use a regex, you could preserve the last character using a replacement.

```
str.replace(/^0+(.)/, "$1");
```

Comment: +1 for a perfect solution, but I've accepted the answer that was more along the lines of my question (I was looking for regex to exclude, not replace the last character). But still, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished pretty simply without RegEx by using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt("[your string here]");
```

**Example**

```
var num1 = "0000"; 
var num2 = "0010";
var num3 = "1";
var num4 = "100050";

console.log(parseInt(num1)); //  --> "0"
console.log(parseInt(num2)); //  --> "10"
console.log(parseInt(num3)); //  --> "1"
console.log(parseInt(num4)); //  --> "100050"
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuZ23/) to play with.

Comment: This is true for the examples I gave, but I forgot to include hexadecimal values. Oops, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
/(^0+(?=0$))|(^0+)/
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vA7dV2)

Comment: This also seems to match non-leading zeros, e.g. in `10000` it will match all zeros except the last one. However, they are not leading zeros so nothing should match.

Comment: you were correct I missed a ^ next to the firs 0 like ^0

Comment: +1 because your solution works for the examples I had before, but this doesn't work for input `"0"`. I expect `"0" --> "0"`. Not perfect, but it's pretty good.